# i need a sample code or code to read and write annotations along with status back to a new pdf doc?

Tags: c#-4.0, syncfusion

I need to write back the annotation status to new pdf with upgraded version. Below is the code I am using for it.

I tried Syncfusion beta version 17.0

```
PdfLoadedDocument docSource = new PdfLoadedDocument(@"D:\Output1_annotaions.pdf");
PdfLoadedDocument docDestination = new PdfLoadedDocument(@"D:\Output1.pdf");

//Get annotations of first page and read destination of first page
PdfLoadedPage pageDestination = docDestination.Pages[0] as PdfLoadedPage;
PdfLoadedPage pageSource = docSource.Pages[0] as PdfLoadedPage;

//Get annotation objects
PdfLoadedAnnotationCollection annotations = pageSource.Annotations;

//loop through annotation objects
foreach (var item in annotations)
{
    pageDestination.Annotations.Add((PdfAnnotation)item);
}

//Save destination document
docDestination.Save(@"D:\Output1.pdf");

//close the documents
docDestination.Close(true);
docSource.Close(true);
```

I need to write all annotations from one version pdf to newer version pdf along with status nested replies for annotations using syncfusion.

Comment: And what is your code doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example which you have used will not completely import all the annotations present in the source PDF to destination PDF. In order to import annotation from one document to another you may use the below code example:

```
///Loads the source and destination PDF
PdfLoadedDocument sourcePDF = new PdfLoadedDocument(DataPathBase+"Input.pdf");
PdfLoadedDocument destinationPDF = new PdfLoadedDocument(DataPathBase+"sample.pdf");

string xfdfFilePath = DataPathOutput + "Export_.xfdf";
//Export annotation data to XFDF file
sourcePDF.ExportAnnotations(xfdfFilePath, AnnotationDataFormat.XFdf);

//Import annotation data from XFDF file
destinationPDF.ImportAnnotations(xfdfFilePath, AnnotationDataFormat.XFdf);

//Save imported PDF document
destinationPDF.Save(DataPathOutput+"Output.pdf");

//close the documents
destinationPDF.Close(true);
sourcePDF.Close(true);
```

You can refer the below UG documentation for the same:
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-annotations#importing-annotations-from-xfdf-file

However, using this code does not import the annotations with status properly in some PDF documents. This is confirmed to be defect and the fix for this issue will be included in our 2019 Volume 1 SP1 release which will be available by April 2019 tentatively.

The status of this issue fix can be tracked using following link.
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/5430/status-and-layer-is-not-preserved-in-resultant-pdf-while-importing-annotation-from-xfdf

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,

Dilli babu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i tried using the mentioned code and for some extent my requirement is fullfiled.